# get values an array and return color to [style.backgroundColor] - Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I want to check the div's value and if the value is `>`,`<` and `===` return the color to [style.backgroundColor].

```js
public getColor(): string {
    const percent = this.file.[0].file2.file3[0].percentValue;
    if (percent > 50) {
      return '#4B8A08';
    } else if (percent <= 50 && percent > 40) {
      return '#FFBF00';
    } else if (percent < 40) {
      return '#FF8000';
    }
  }
```

I'm getting only one number maybe because `[0]` but if I remove `[0]` I get error, in HTML I'm using * ngIf with index to get the values and working fine, but in component what I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public getColor(percent:string): string {
        percent = +percent
        if (percent > 50) {
          return '#4B8A08';
        } else if (percent <= 50 && percent > 40) {
          return '#FFBF00';
        } else if (percent < 40) {
          return '#FF8000';
        }
  }
```

and In html

```
<div [style.backgroundColor]="getColor(groupNumbers.person.peopleSkills[0].percentValue)">{{groupNumbers.person.peopleSkills[0].percentValue}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your function should be like. your `percent` variable string. you need to convert into integer.

```
public getColor(): string {
        const percent = +this.squad.squadPeople[0].person.peopleSkills[0].percentValue;
        if (percent > 50) {
          return '#4B8A08';
        } else if (percent <= 50 && percent > 40) {
          return '#FFBF00';
        } else if (percent < 40) {
          return '#FF8000';
        }
  }
```